# Voltage drop through a resistor for a single charge, contrasted to a non-ohmic component

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, ohms-law, energy

Recently I have been reading about how transistors and diodes only drop a limited amount of voltage across their leads for a wide range of currents. So the voltage drop per charge (at a given temperature) is more or less consistent and limited.

A resistor on the other hand can drop any amount of voltage across itself and this really confuses me. So a charge passing through a resistor can drop a wide range of voltage across it, depending mainly on the voltage source and not the actual resistor value.

My question is - **why doesn't a resistor drop a fixed amount of voltage (a per charge quantity) for each charge that passes through it? And why doesn't the amount of voltage drop per charge depend on resistor value, but on potential energy the electron has in the first place.**

An analogy that might illustrate where I'm going wrong with my thinking: let's take gravity and friction - when you drop a body from a certain height through a certain friction. Would a small amount of friction drop any amount of potential energy? Would it not drop a fixed amount depending on how significant the friction is, the rest of the potential energy being converted to kinetic energy?

I have gone through a few sources on Ohm's law (for example the resistance curves for ohmic and non-ohmic components), the Drude model and quantum field theory (just the basics I could understand, no math) and I still don't get it. How can an electron drop a varying amount of potential energy regardless of the value of a resistor. Why doesn't it drop a limited amount, converting the rest into kinetic energy?

I am sorry to be asking a rather basic question, but despite my best efforts I have not found an answer.

Comment: I think maybe part of the problem is the assumption that a single electon's energy somehow changes.  Current and voltage are the aggregate of many bazzillion electrons.  You can't apply Ohm's law to a single electron.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voltage drop through a resistor compared to a Zener diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535332/voltage-drop-through-a-resistor-compared-to-a-zener-diode)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I asked that question yesterday, but was told it was not clear enough so that I am asking very specifically in a separate question.

Comment: A resistor does drop a fixed amount of voltage per charge. For a resistor, an increase in current (which is an increase in charge per second) results in a proportional increase in voltage.

Comment: That's not encouraged here. You have to edit your original question then. Nevertheless, this will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Actually it was encouraged here yesterday as you can see from the comments. How do you know who to believe then?

Comment: Pangus, thanks for your comment. If that is the case, it would make sense. But then, I'm confused by the fact that voltage is a per charge quantity. So we are saying that electric potential per charge is fixed for the resistor, yet also saying that the resistor can drop varying amounts of voltage, the definition of which is electrical potential per charge. What am I missing here?

Comment: @ZhelyazkoGrudov Voltage is *not* a "per charge quantity" - if you're talking about the voltage of the power supply, that is a property of the supply - of the *electric field* - and not the charges, and if you're looking at the charge carriers themselves they have a *fixed* "charge" which is measured in coulombs and not volts.

Comment: An important point I was missing. Thanks a lot. Also if you write a book, and I'm still kicking I would love to read it! You explain things really well. Out of curiosity, what do you do for a living?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather complicated, because Ohm's law is classical and an approximation, as is the Drude model, while actual electrons are quantum objects.

Let's consider an extreme simplification with no conductor at all. Imagine two plates with an electric field of V volts between them. A stationary electron leaves the -ve plate and accelerates towards the positive plate. It linearly accumulates kinetic energy as it accelerates; by the time it hits the positive plate it's carrying V * 1.602176634×10−19 J of kinetic energy. This is in fact a handy unit called the [electron-volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt) and is often used when discussing particle accelerators.

So 1V field transfers 1eV of kinetic energy per electron, a 2V field produces 2eV and so on.

Now let's introduce a classical collision object halfway between the plates. This imaginary object takes away all the kinetic energy on collision, but then leaves the electron free to accelerate again. If it's halfway along, we see that it takes away half the energy: in this new system with a 1V field an electron will have 0.5eV kinetic energy when it hits the positive plate, having lost 0.5eV to the collider.

Crucially this varies linearly with V *and nothing else* - as we increase the field the collider continues to take half of the energy.

Now, in a real conductor there are lots of colliders, and collisions are probabilistic, so at that point you either have to do the calculus and integrate over the probability distribution functions, or go for an intuitive approach.

The electron *doesn't know* what the resistance is. It has a kinetic energy and a probability of collision. We can see intuitively certain properties of conductivity - if we make the resistor twice as long, there are twice as many opportunities to collide.

Double the voltage doesn't increase the probability of collision, but it does double the amount of kinetic energy the electron has at the time of collision - which it then loses *all* of. Hence doubling the power dissipation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's clear, concise and to the point. I really appreciate it. It also allows me to understand why voltage dividers work, which is something I didn't intuitively get before.

Comment: Sorry can I ask you if this assumption is correct - in the event of adding a second resistor current is going to drop until kinetic energy lost from collisions at both resistors = potential energy the battery provides. In effect, I'm just restating ohms law to try and confirm if my understanding of kinetic and potential energy is correct.

Comment: I think it's important to recognise that Ohm's law is a statistical aggregate; any individual electron has a somewhat random amount of k.e., and can do non-Newtonian things. You can say "the total energy (joules) lost from collisions in the conductor == the number of electrons that flow through it (coulombs) times the field strength moving those electrons (volts)" if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Is there some book you can recommend that goes over this, for someone with out the mathematical rigour to understand quantum field theory? I've been studying a lot about different components, circuits, etc. but it's these basics that still confuse me. I cannot wrap my head around how an electron can (on average) lose only a portion of its kinetic energy on collision in a resistor, but then we say that all potential energy is dropped in a resistor.

Comment: And in any case the difference between charge on the positive and negative end of a resistor should differ in kinetic energy, potential energy slowly decreasing as the electrons move further away from the negative terminal of the voltage source? I know you're going to say I am wrong, but I do not know why!! Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I'm not aware of a really precise book on this and after some years of answering questions on Stackexchange about the misconceptions of electrons that are taught to beginners, I'm thinking I might have to write one when I retire. Mind you, I've never fully crunched the quantum mechanics maths on semiconductors and am slighly hazy on some of the details myself.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems hidden in your question.
First, a diode does not drop a fixed voltage irregardless of the current. The voltage does change with the current, but it does so in such an extremely nonlinear way that it appears to reach a value and then not change anymore. So, your question becomes "how is it possible to have nonlinear resistors, like a diode?"
Second, you are trying to reduce the behavior of an ensemble of carrier, where probabilities and statistics are what allow us to describe their V-I characteristic, to the behavior of a single carrier. This will not get you much far. You need to consider large numbers of carriers to be able to explain those neat V-I curves.

So, let's see your question as: "how come the resistor has such a strikingly linear V-I characteristic while the diode has such a strikingly nonlinear characteristic that seems to go vertical at a certain value of V?"
The free electron model gives a reasonable *qualitative* of ohmic resistance as, basically, viscous drag by means of collisions with the atoms of the material lattice. Basically, instead of seeing electrons accelerating between points at different potentials (like a pebble accelerates when moving between points at different heights), we see electrons moving at a constant drift velocity because their motion is 'reset' with each collision (much in the same way a speck of dust falls with constant velocity due to the viscous drag in air - if you have access to French's "Newtonian Mechanics" there you will find a wonderful explanation of this). Constant drift velocity means constant current density and this leads to a constant current in responde to a constant voltage applied.

This 'drag' is also present in semiconductors, but the conduction in these materials is different because it is due to two different mechanisms: drift and diffusion. But let's forget about that for a moment. The most striking difference between an ohmic conductor and a semiconductor is the fact that in the former you have a sea of conduction electrons at your disposal and all you need to set them in motion is to apply a potential difference, while in a semiconductor your sea is buried under an energy gap and you need to 'pump' the carriers in the conduction band before you can set them in motion with a potential difference. Heating the semiconductor will add energy to the electrons so that more will end up in the conduction band (and holes will be left in the valence band), enhancing conduction - semiconductor's resistance will increase with temperature (the exact oppositve of what happens with ohmic conductors where increasing temperature increases the probability of collision with the lattice and thus increases resistance).
The energy distribution of the carriers is also important and here you cannot do away with the statistics. It turns out that in first approximation the density of carriers decreases exponentially with the 'energy distance' from a reference level called Fermi level, so if you were able to build a device where you could somehow shift this distribution up and down by applying a voltage to it, you will end up with an exponential variation of the current through it. The inner working of a diode is more complicated than that, requires different types of semiconductors, an understanding of diffusion currents and potential barrier and basically at least a chapter of a book, but the key is that you can change the height of the potential barrier by applying a voltage, and as a consequence the populations of carriers that will contribute to the current in the device will vary exponentially.
There still is viscous drag in the device, but it's effect is hidden by the humongous exponential variation of current with voltage.

To simplify things more, this exponential curve is sometimes approximated by a piecewise linear characteristic: sometimes with a vertical trait at the threshold voltage (in which case we think as the diode as having zero internal resistance) and sometimes with a slanted trait starting at the threshold voltage.
But the real curve is exponential, so the 'did not conduct until Vthreshold' and 'starts conducting after Vthreshol' is just an approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a look in this to try and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Another view of diodes versus resistors is this:

- diodes provide a logarithm function of voltage versus current.

The typical silicon diode, whether operating at 1 picoAmp or 1milliAmp, will increase the voltage by 0.018 volts when you double the current.

- resistors provide a linear function of voltage versus current.

Thus for 1 picoAmp doubling to 2 pA thru a 1,000 ohm resistor the voltage increases from 1 nanoVolt to 2 nanoVolts (which some voltmeters can measure).

And for 1 milliamp doubling to 2 milliamp thru a 1,000 ohm resistor the voltage increases from 1 volt to 2 volts.

Again, the diodes are very useful for many reasons; I worked with people who exploited the log behavior of diodes in implementing the Relative Signal Strength Indicator RSSI
for cellphone. One customer wanted a dynamic range of 80dB (10,000:1 change in input RF voltage) at 300MHz from the IF chain. I ran a few sims using our typical (corporate_wide) topology, and showed there would be oscillation. So the customer altered the requirements: 60dB dynamic range at 10MHz (which was the 2nd IF). Result: no oscillation, and a very useful RSSI over temperature and VDD and process, as one small circuit in a huge GSM receiver chip.

Thus the log behavior is tempting to be used to handle extreme signal strength variations, but you need to verify with your semiconductor_process people if that is viable.

And watch out for feedback through the shared bias nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> *So a charge passing through a resistor can drop a wide range of
> voltage across it, depending mainly on the voltage source and not the
> actual resistor value.*

Ohm's law: \$V = IR\$

Rate of change of charge is current hence a moving charge (in effect a current) drops a voltage across a resistor proportional to the value of resistance.

> *why doesn't a resistor drop a fixed amount of voltage (a per charge
> quantity) for each charge that passes through it?

Because it depends on resistance

> *And why doesn't the
> amount of voltage drop per charge depend on resistor value*

It does.

Comment: Not a very helpful answer. I know of Ohm's law as I have said in the question itself. You are not answering the question at all. Does it really depend on resistance? I'm pretty sure it depends on voltage source. Changing the voltage source changes the voltage drop across the resistor. Changing the resistor value does not change voltage drop across the resistor; only the current.

Comment: Andy is right, it does depend on resistance. It works both ways. If you have a current source that controls the current through the resistance, the resistance sets the voltage over it based on the current.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the current source which determines what voltage needs to be provided for specific resistance, since it's the active element. In any case, it does not answer the question for a individual charge, which is what is confusing. I appreciate your response though.

Comment: I think there are two major remarks to be made regarding your question. Firstly, a current source _I_ doesn't determine what voltage "needs to be **provided**" to a resistor _R_, it determines what voltage drops across _R_ as a consequence of Ohm's law. In other words, the _I_ you impose to _R_ will determine a specific voltage value _RI_ that you can measure as a **consequence**. Instead, if you connect a voltage source it will determine what current you will see/measure flowing through _R_. 1/2

Comment: Secondly and loosely speaking, voltages, currents and resistances are "macro-quantities" that describe the behaviour of ensemble of particles and charges. I dare say that such concepts aren't adequate for answering a part of your question: a single charge doesn't see a resistance when it travels, it only bounces on atoms composing a material's lattice so that its average speed is reduced by such interactions; at a macroscopic level and for many particles, the average speed and its reduction caused by the material are then interpreted as current and resistance, respectively. 2/2

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Should I not consider voltage as a per charge quantity in this case?

Answer (score 0):

First, an appeal to common sense. Consider what happens when you connect a resistor directly across the terminals of a battery. The voltage across the resistor must be the same as the battery voltage. That must be true even if you then replace the battery with one with a different voltage.

A resistor is a constriction in a wire, like a narrow section in a water pipe. A common type of resistor is a very thin metal film deposited on a ceramic core.

How hard is it to push one electron per second through a thin metal film? Not very. How hard is it to push six billion billion electrons a second (one amp) through the same metal film? Much harder! The voltage is the push that forces electrons around the circuit. Looking at it that way, Ohm's law makes sense.